# My MacBook Air is giving me static when touching

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I know that is because maybe the plug I'm plugin it is not grounded, I have the 3 pin power adapter, I live in Argentina where voltage is 220v from the power plug, is there any way to ground my MacBook in order to not feel that static sensation, because I feel like its gonna broke something on the MacBook.

Is there any wrong on using my MacBook with this static sensation when rubbing it ?

Comment: Static build up comes from carpets and the chair you sit on.  So it is you who is charged. To test touch something else (metallic) before touching Mac.

Comment: here is an excellent answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314954/46541

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my adapter does have the metal grounding

Comment: on both ends ? ? the wall and the charger

Comment: I dont know about the wall, I just use an adapter with 3 pins to connect