# MB Pro 13" 2017 - Small Shocks / Static Charge when on charge Grounding through me. Stops when I take feet off floor / unplug macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

I know this question has been seen a lot - and I'm relatively sure its safe.

Just wondering how to get a grounding charger.
I have 3 pin UK plug with metal grounding pin HOWEVER there is no connector between the grounding ring on the power brick and the slot the ring slides into when you assemble the charger.

Do apple sell a UK 3 pin grounded plug that ACTUALLY connects to the ground on the power brick?
It seems the one shipped with mine only has a metal ground pin for show as it doesn't actually connect to the power bricks ground

Comment: I’m not sure USB-C and PD even earths from the transformer to the MacBook anymore. Here is what worked in MagSafe days when the outer most pin (1 and 5) were both solid ground. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17575/how-to-properly-ground-a-macbook-pro