# Buzzing sound through MBA earphones while charging

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, apple-silicon

I have got a MBA M1 base variant and am in India with 220 V @ 50 Hz power supply. Currently, my MBA is plugged in (and 100% charged) and through my earphones I am hearing a buzzing sound. If I turn off the power then the sound vanishes.

More interestingly though, if I touch my hand to any area on the metal surface the sound vanishes. Likewise, if the power is plugged-in and I drag my hand through any area of the metal surface then there is a distinctive vibration I can feel which is absent when my hand is resting.

Is this normal behaviour? Is there any chance of damage of any kind? Could this be a grounding issue? I'm pretty sure that the power is grounded (but not 100% sure).

Edit : Additional Comment -

In case it's relevant I bought the MacBook through official online store of Apple so no chance of a run-in with power rating issues. Also, the power supply at my place is rock-steady.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an earthing issue. If power supply & mains plug and socket are all correctly earthed, this should lessen or disappear.

Some PSUs aren't earthed* - this I've always considered a manufacturer failing.

Technically it's not 'dangerous' as the mains leakage from a switch-mode power suppy is a known quantity, but it does upset people.

*See [How to properly ground a MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17575/how-to-properly-ground-a-macbook-pro) for details of how even with a three pin plug your Mac may still not actually be correctly earthed/grounded.

Comment: I have confirmed now that things are properly earthed!

Answer (score 0):

This used to happen to a family member's MBA when it was plugged into a specific outlet and placed on top of a limestone countertop. Touching it stopped the buzzing. Absolutely a grounding issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/320057)