# Manually ground the UK wall plug for macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro

The ground pin of the UK power plug is not connected to the macbook, causing small shock if use when charging.

While the old extension plug is properly grounded, it's more cumbersome than the standard plug.

I checked that the "ground" of the two end of extension plug is shorted.  So I wonder if it is possible to simply short the metal button to the ground pin of standard plug, using a jump wire.

Any tried it before?

Comment: Have you got pictures? There are several versions. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17575/how-to-properly-ground-a-macbook-pro?rq=1

Comment: @Tetsujin great, seems like I overlooked this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345631/148844