# My Macbook Pro gives electric shocks. How can i measure it?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging

I'm getting electric shocks/strong tingling sensation with my Macbook Pro whenever the power chord is plugged. It happens all the time, anywhere, and is unrelated to wearing shoes or not. It's disturbing enough to prevent normal use, and really makes me wonder if it is a health hazard (what's the limit again for DC, 30 milliamps before you're history?).

I tried measuring it with a multimeter. I got some readings at 18V (quite typical of a charger voltage).

I'm unhappy with this, and the net is littered with people complaining about this same problem.

How can I properly measure the voltage?  What do regulations say?

Answer (score 1):

you already answered your first question. as for your second that depends on what regulation you are talking about. I could tell you what is causing it but you didnt ask that

Comment: I would be interested to know what is causing it.

Comment: its about earths

Comment: its about earth, its been answered here [link(https://superuser.com/questions/462244/electric-shock-mild-vibrating-sensation-on-macbook-pro-when-charging)   [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10545/is-it-bad-that-my-macbook-air-is-passing-me-electricity and also at apple [link] (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3969131?tstart=0) also some countries don't use earths and the countries that do not all extension leads are earth enabled . so one needs the long cable that came with the charger and an earthed outlet @iCyberPaul

Comment: yes, it's about earth. And the charger that is sold has no earth plug on it, so the electric plug wont matter much. What i'm really interested about, is what regulations say about it or practical ways to solve this (without drilling a hole in the aluminium case and running a cable to earth :-) )

Comment: the long cable that comes with the charger IS earthed the travle charger ( the small clip on one isn't. the tingle one feels is below any "regulation" . .  zzzz